# How to access specific elements with getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I want to access the input elements where the type is "checkbox" and ignore the input tags that has the type "text".

When I use the code bellow I get an error message:

```
TypeError: outerField.getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

Dos anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

The javascript:

```
 outerField = document.getElementsByClassName("outerField");
 checkboxes = outerField.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

The html markup:

```
 <section id="images">
  <div class="outerField">
    <input type="checkbox">
        <img src="lorem.jpg">
    <div class="innerField">
         <input type="text" value ="">
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: It return a list of elements. Access it like an array.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. The function is called "getElementsByClassName" not "getElementByClassName" (notice the "s" in "Elements").

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

You get back every element which has the class "outerField" not a single element. You have to access a particular element in this [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

In your example this should work:

```
 outerField = document.getElementsByClassName("outerField");
 checkboxes = outerField.item(0).getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelectorAll` which uses a CSS like syntax to filter for the class *and* the checkboxes:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.outerField input[type=checkbox]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementByClassName("outerField");
```

should be

```
document.getElementsByClassName("outerField"); //s was missing:typo
```

and outerField is an array , use it like

```
outerField[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Answer (score 1):

method name is getElementsByClassName not getElementByClassName.
You will get a collection of elements in return

Comment: That was just a typo in question, otherwise the OP would have gotten a different error.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector[All]` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)) makes your life a lot easier:

```js
var cbxs = document.querySelectorAll('.outerField > input[type=checkbox]');
// demo: show length of cbxs within 'div.outerField')
document.querySelector('.outerField')
  .appendChild(document.createTextNode('length of checkboxes ' + cbxs.length));
```

```html
<section id="images">
  <div class="outerField">
    <input type="checkbox">
        <img src="lorem.jpg">
    <div class="innerField">
         <input type="text" value ="">
    </div> 
  </div>
```